# Azure DevOps: Can not load nuget package from feed in Azure Pipeline if feed name is used

Tags: azure, azure-devops, yaml, nuget, azure-pipelines

I have a Azure feed named `sampleFeed` in a project `sampleProject` which is in organization `sampleOrganization`. When I am restoring packages in my build pipeline I am getting error `##[error]The nuget command failed with exit code(1) and error(Unable to load the service index for source https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/sampleOrganization/_packaging/sampleFeed/nuget/v3/index.json.`

yaml pipeline steps to restore package is as below:

```
 - task: NuGetAuthenticate@1
  displayName: 'Nuget Authenticate'

 - task: NuGetCommand@2
  displayName: 'NuGet Restore'
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '**/SampleService.csproj'
    vstsFeed: $(parameter-feedName)
```

- In `parameter-feedName` I am passing feed name `sampleFeed`
- Feed scope is project.
- Azure feed and my build pipeline are in the same project.

On debugging I have found that path created automatically by the task NuGetCommand@2 is invalid. Valid URI of the feed is https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/sampleOrganization/sampleProject/_packaging/sampleFeed/nuget/v3/index.json where as URI created by task has no project information in path.

When I pass feed GUID (eg: `81ffa918-1abb-4e49-8a2c-dfec591be544/b7576616-ad83-4e2c-a553-d8f1ceeb5dfc`) instead of feedName, correct URI is formed and pipeline works without any issue.

My question is am I doing something wrong or is this issue with the task NuGetCommand@2?
I don't want to work with the GUID as to figure out feed GUID additional manual steps are required.

Comment: Hi there, As @Stepness answered, could you please test to to use `sampleProject/sampleFeed` for `vstsFeed` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a project scope feed you may need to add the project in front of the feed name, like `sampleProject/sampleFeed` inside `parameter-feedName`.

It should be like the first example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/nuget-command-v2?view=azure-pipelines#examples).

```yaml
# Restore from a project scoped feed in the same organization
- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    feedsToUse: 'select'
    vstsFeed: 'my-project/my-project-scoped-feed'
    includeNuGetOrg: false
    restoreSolution: '**/*.sln'
```

Comment: This works, thanks @Stepness